# iPhone: initialize object in controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am very new to objective-c and having a problem to initialize an object in view controller. The problem I am having is that when setTemp method is called, "0" is printed on the screen instead of the value of cTemp I would like it to be. Can anyone help me on this problem?

Below are excerpts of the code I have.

SJT.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
@interface SJT : NSObject {
int cTemp;
}
- (int) newTemp;
@end
```

SJT.m

```
#import "SJT.h"
@implementation SJT
- (int) newTemp
{
    cTemp =  25 + rand() % 8;
    return cTemp;
}
@end
```

SJTViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class SJT;

@interface SJTViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *temp;
    SJT *sjt;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *temp;
@property (retain, nonatomic) SJT *sjt;

- (IBAction) setTemp: (id) sender;

@end
```

SJTViewController.m

```
#import "SJTViewController.h"
#import "SJT.h"

@implementation SJTViewController
@synthesize temp;
@synthesize sjt;



- (IBAction) setTemp: (id) sender
{
    NSString *tempText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",sjt.newTemp];
    temp.text = tempText;
    [tempText release];
}
.
.
.
@end
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for all answers. 

In fact, I should have been more specific about what I am trying to do. 

Saying that I would like to initialize the SJT object when setTemp method is called. Then, method newTemp in SJT object is called to get the initial value of the variable. 

My question is how I can obtain the value of sjt.newTemp from another method in viewcontroller.

Comment: The error was solved. It turned out to be that I forgot to put [[sjt alloc] init]; in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're mistaking property syntax for a method call; i.e.

```
sjt.newTemp
```

would become a call to [sjt newTemp]. Which happens to be exactly what you want, except that you have not specified in your header/implementation that there actually is a property called newTemp.

So, in this scenario what you want to do is either **a)** define the property in the header:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) int newTemp;
```

or **b)**, just call the method *newTemp*:

```
[sjt newTemp]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that `sjt` is not `nil`? You don't provide the code where and instance of `SJT` is constructed. In Objective-C you can call a method on a `nil` reference without error, and if you do so on a method that returns an `int` it will return `0`.

So `sjt.newTemp` will return `0` if `sjt` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Both Jacob and teabot have pointed out valid possible reasons -- which one is correct (or both!) depends on pieces of code we can't see in your post.

Based on what you've written so far, you might not be thinking of `newTemp` as a property, but more as a function call, so I would suggest changing your code to:

```
- (IBAction) setTemp: (id) sender {
  int tempInt = [self.sjt newTemp];
  self.temp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tempInt];
}
```

which is functionally equivalent.  Note the convenience constructor `stringWithFormat:` returns an autoreleased object, which is then retained by the `retain` property `text` of the `temp` `UILabel`.

The other thing to double-check in your code is that `self.sjt` is not `nil`, which is exactly what teabot said.  Objective-C returns 0 on method calls invoked on a `nil` pointer.